# Is this EVAP valve solenoid or EGR valve solenoid?

Tags: mazda, egr, evap, protege

[This](https://www.rockauto.com/en/moreinfo.php?pk=10115668&cc=1416833&pt=4936&jsn=912&jsn=912) is listed under [Evap purge valve solenoid](https://www.rockauto.com/en/catalog/mazda,2003,protege5,2.0l+l4,1416833,exhaust+&+emission,vapor+canister+purge+valve+/+solenoid,4936), but I believe it is actually an EGR valve solenoid. Can somebody please confirm?

Below is 2 pictures of what I believe EGR valve solenoid. Notice the black cap (1st picture under the electrical connector) which can be removed then put on another position as in 2nd picture? I'm confused which position is correct, and how to make sure (like can blow air into or something)?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you click on the part number instead of the Info button, it shows the part you've listed is for the 2002-2003 Protoge5. Under the other section for Daily Driver, it shows the parts listed are for multiple different Mazda vehicles. If you don't have the Protoge5, I'd be looking at the other one. It is not an EGR valve, though. It is under a separate listing and has a (what appears to be) cast iron body to it.

Comment: This link https://www.rockauto.com/en/catalog/mazda,2003,protege5,2.0l+l4,1416833,exhaust+&+emission,egr+valve+control+solenoid+/+motor,4380 lists the EGR valve solenoid

Comment: The 1st picture is for a different model ... it's not the EGR valve solenoid. You are right, the 2nd picture is the one for the EGR solenoid. These are not the same thing, though are very similar. The reason they put pictures in the listings is so you can verify what you have before you go to replace it.

Comment: My car is Protege5 2003. I think Rockauto is wrong.